# Le suffixe du gentilé « Guatémaltèque » est-il inusité : détails sur le suffixe et la formation ?

Tags: origine-ou-raison, diacritiques, lexique, suffixes, gentilés

Après avoir [lu](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/etats-unis/201812/29/01-5209489-trump-impute-aux-democrates-la-mort-denfants-migrants-en-retention.php) que deux enfants provenant du [Guatemala](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guatemala) étaient morts en rétention aux États-Unis à une semaine d'intervalle pendant qu'on s'empiffre, je m'interroge sur le gentilé « Guatémaltèque » et incidemment sur la raison de la différence dans l'emploi de l'accent aigu dans le nom du pays (Fr : [Guatémala](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000019509867&dateTexte=) ; Qc : [Guatemala](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1944) ; Fr/Qc : Guatémaltèque).

- Quel est le suffixe exact dans le gentilé « guatémaltèque » et
  pourquoi le gentilé diffère-t-il apparemment tant du nom du pays, comment s'est opérée cette formation ; y a-t-il d'autres gentilés qui sont ainsi suffixés ?
- Incidemment, en ce qui a trait au nom du pays, l'accent aigu est-il indicateur d'une plus grande lexicalisation du nom ; y a-t-il une raison
  expliquant la différence (d'approche par exemple) entre la France et
  le Québec à cet effet ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Le suffixe de gentilé pour le Guatemala est -tèque. C'est le seul pays qui a ce suffixe, mais il est utilisé pour des villes de la région (sud du Mexique et Guatemala). Voir par exemple [une liste des gentilés sur Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_de_gentil%C3%A9s).

Le gentilé nous vient sans surprise de l'espagnol qui l'a pris au [nahuatl](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nahuatl), qui était la langue des [Aztèques](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azt%C3%A8ques) qui régnaient sur la région jusqu'à la colonisation espagnole. En nahuatl, [le suffixe *-teca* signifie « habitant de »](https://ketzalitorres.wordpress.com/2011/04/01/la-pronunciacion-del-nahuatl-y-los-gentilicios/). C'est donc un [emprunt de gentilé](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_de_gentil%C3%A9s#Suffixes_formateurs_de_gentil%C3%A9s), comme -iote du grec ou -i de l'arabe.

C'est le seul nom de pays qui ait ce suffixe parce que c'est un des deux seul noms de pays qui [viennent du nahuatl](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?Guatemala). L'autre, *Mexico*, vient du mot [*Mexica*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexicas#%C3%89tymologie) qui est au départ un nom de peuple ayant ensuite donné son nom à la région qu'ils contrôlaient et non l'inverse. ([L'étymologie de *Nicaragua* est disputée](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histoire_du_Nicaragua).)

Pour ce qui est de l'accent ou non dans le nom du pays, il n'y a pas d'accent en espagnol, mais [l'état Français](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000019509867&dateTexte=) en met un en français. *Guatemala* est la version importée et *Guatémala* est la version francisée. Comme on prononce de toute façon *Guatemala* a l'espagnole ([gwatemala] et pas *<strike>[gatəmala]</strike>), l'accent ne s'entend pas, donc il a tendance à passer inaperçu. Il y a encore plus d'hésitation sur le *Venezuela* ou *Vénézuela* ou *Vénézuéla* ou *Vénézuèla* (c'est comme ça qu'on prononce en français, et pourtant l'accent grave est rare).

Answer (score 4):

Guatémaltèque est est un emprunt à l'adjectif espagnol *guatemalteco*, lui-même un emprunt au nahuatl *cuauhtēmaltēcatl* ("Guatemala" vient lui-même du nahuatl *Cuauhtēmallān*).

L'adjectif nahuatl se décompose en cuauhtēmal-tēca-tl où -tēca est un suffixe de gentilé similaire à -ais.e ou -ain.e en français et -tl la marque du singulier non-possédé. C'est ce même suffixe qui se retrouve dans d'autres noms de peuple mésoaméricains tels que az**tèque**, ol**mèque**, zapo**tèque**, chia**panèque** ou mix**tèque** (La forme exacte du suffixe dépend de la dernière consonne de la racine). On le retrouve également, dans une forme figée et lexicalisée, dans le nom du Mexi**que**.

Tous ces suffixes en -Cēca- ont été adaptés en -eca en Espagnol, formant des adjectifs épicènes que le français a empruntés avec la graphie -èque, en leur conservant leur caractère épicène. *Guatemaltec-* est une exception à cette règle puisqu'il présente un masculin en -o et un féminin en -a, mais le français n'a pas suivi l'espagnol sur ce point.