# Formation de gentilés pour des quartiers (de Montréal : Côte-des-Neiges et Notre-Dame-de-Grâce) etc. ?

Tags: québec, suffixes, géographie, gentilés

On sait qu'il y a une grande diversité de gentilés en français, incluant par [emprunt](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/33223), et que les [suffixes formateurs](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_de_gentil%C3%A9s#Suffixes_formateurs_de_gentil%C3%A9s) se déclinent selon certains axes, qu'il s'agisse de gentilés pour des villes ou des pays ou qu'ils soient plus anciens ou pour certaines régions. Mais qu'en est-il pour des quartiers ou des arrondissements ? Par exemple, l'Université de Montréal se situe dans le quartier *Côte-des-Neiges* auquel est adjoint le quartier *Notre-Dame-de-Grâce* pour former l'[arrondissement](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrondissements_de_Montr%C3%A9al) *Côte-des-Neiges–Notre-Dame-de-Grâce*.

La [Commission de toponymie](https://toponymie.gouv.qc.ca/ct/toponymie-municipale/gentiles/lesgentilesliste.aspx) du Québec identifie une contribution anonyme de 1986 et des variantes pour le premier quartier et un forme anglaise pour le second avec un commentaire (et je confirme qu'il y a alternance de codes chez un Montréalais francophone pour prononcer le nom du quartier) :

**Côte-des-neiges** (quartier)

> Côte-des-Neigien, Côte-des-Neigienne (1986)
> Variante (s) : Côtedeneigien (1954); Côte-des-Neigeois; Neige-Côtier.

**Notre-Dame-de-Grâce** (quartier)

> NDGer (1986) (forme anglaise)
> Commentaire : La population anglophone
> abrège très régulièrement le nom de ce quartier en NDG, prononcé
> figurativement [N-DI-DJI].

---

- En s'appuyant sur les grandes lignes servant à l'élaboration des
  gentilés selon la catégorie de lieux, le toponyme, sa morphologie, sa graphie,
  la productivité des suffixes reliés et tout autre critère qu'on
  jugera pertinent (en résumé : pourquoi), lequel des gentilés
  présentés ou quel gentilé préférerait-on (ou comment classerait-on
  par ordre de préférence ceux qui sont présentés) pour les habitants de l'un et l'autre
  de ces deux quartiers ?
- À quoi pourrait ressembler un gentilé qui désigne les habitants de
  l'arrondissement (*Côte-des-Neiges–Notre-Dame-de-Grâce*) ; s'agirait-il simplement de relier deux gentilés par un trait d'union, ou non ?

Answer (score 4):

Il y a plusieurs façons courantes pour former un gentilé : soit on revient à l'orgine latine des mots, soit on garde la forme française. Ensuite on ajoute un suffixe. S'agissant des nom composés avec trait d'union, le gentilé est généralement plus simple (perte d'un ou plusieurs éléments, ex: Saint-Etienne => Stéphanois), et l'ordre des élément peut être changés.

Outre les proposition déjà avancées, on pourrait tenter :

> - Neigecôtien, Neigecôtois (pour Côte-des-Neiges)
> - Graço-Neigien, Graço-neigeois (pour Côte-des-Neiges–Notre-Dame-de-Grâce)

Un gentilé comportant 3 éléments ou plus me semblerait d'une grande lourdeur. Je note d'ailleurs les exemples suivants : Bellecombien ([Notre-Dame-de-Bellecombe](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notre-Dame-de-Bellecombe)), Landais ([Notre-Dame-des-Landes](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notre-Dame-des-Landes)), Notre-Damien ([Notre-Dame-du-Nord](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notre-Dame-du-Nord)).

on pourrait faire plus étymologique (et prétentieux) dans l'esprit de germanopratin (Saint-Germain-des-prés) ou de l'horrible Altoséquanais (hauts de seine) :

> - Grationivien ou Grationivois (pour Côte-des-Neiges–Notre-Dame-de-Grâce)
> - Costonivien ou Costonivois (pour Côte-des-Neiges)
>
> ou encore
>
> - Nivocostien, Nivocostois (pour Côte-des-Neiges)

Pour l'anecdote, la mode actuelle semble être plutôt à la simplicité qu'à l'étymologie. Voir aurhalpins (pour habitant d'Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes) ou Seine-et-Marnais, par exemple.

Comment: @mastödantirâfamî J'ai ajouté des précisions dans ma réponse.